# prevent a value repeating in the same day

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to develop php simple script that can be entered records like this: (mysql is my db engine)

```
id (auto increment, primary key)
StudentName
StudentNumber
ClassName
Grade
ScreeningDate (mm/dd/yyyy)
```

etc.

now what I need is to prevent the StudentNumber to be entered in the same day, for example, if other user has entered it already, then a message says: this Number was already added for today...

In other words, i need before the insert, to check if the studentNumber is there, then give the message, otherwise, will add the row normally...... hence, next day, it is okay, they can add same studentNumber again like yesterday.... something like PrimaryKey but only for today! how is this possible?

Comment: What is screeningdate?  Can you use that to determine what date the row was added?  If not, add a timestamp column and test against that

Comment: one but not the best one is to use trigger before insert http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html you can also check if such row is inserted with select and if it's then show error.

Answer (score 1):

Create a unique compound index on (ScreeningDate, StudentNumber). Then `INSERT` operations that would place duplicates into your table will fail with duplicate-key errors.

You will need to detect this duplicate-key situation in your PHP code and return the appropriate message to the user who attempted to insert the dup. The INSERT statement will return an error.

Or, you can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` if you want to update the row if it already exists. Read this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

To create the index, do this:

```
ALTER TABLE whatever ADD UNIQUE INDEX NoDailyDups (ScreeningDate, StudentNumber)
```

This approach has the advantage that it works correctly, without explicit table locking, even on a very busy system. If two users happen to be racing to insert the first item for a particular student and day, one of them will win and the other will get the duplicate-key error.

Notice also that your table is slightly denormalized -- it contains slightly redundant data. You might want to create another table containing the columns `StudentNumber` and `StudentName`, and move the student names out of this table.

Comment: I didn't know how to add this compound key to my tables (until now) so my work around was to do an md5 hash on the parameters I wanted to create a unique key. (Example: $uniqueKey = md5($studentNumber . $screeningDate;) Then had a column that stored those hashes and it had to be unique. Typically I didn't care if there was a second attempt so I used INSERT IGNORE.

Answer (score 0):

Do a select to get the specified student number on today's date like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE StudentNumber = 123 AND DATE(ScreeningDate) = CURDATE()
```

If any rows are returned, there's a record for this student number on today's date, otherwise you are free to insert. The `DATE` function extracts the date part of a date, i.e. the date month and year

Comment: unfortunately this tactic has a potential race condition between the SELECT and the insert.

Comment: Does it? Would you be able to give an example of how this might occur with this query and PHP, please?

Answer (score -1):

This may not be efficient but you can fetch all the rows of current date first:

```
SELECT StudentNumber, ScreeningDate FROM tablename WHERE StudentNumber = '22' AND ScreeningDate = 'mm/dd/yyyy';
```

And don't add(insert query) if the above query returned more than 0 rows(it will be one generally).

Comment: unfortunately this tactic has a potential race condition between the `SELECT` and the insert.

Comment: I know this is not the best one and should be avoided. Even Jonathon's answer is almost same. :D